# Error while importing configuration module: No module named 'app' [aerich]

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, tortoise-orm

I found myself playing with the python backend and for that I used **fastapi** and **tortoise-orm**. However, it was a pain to manually update the database after each change to the **tortoise-orm models**, so I used the **out-of-the-box aerich tool** which was specially developed for this purpose. However, I have a problem with importing and I'm exhausting because I don't know what am I doing wrong.

For some reason, after initializing the migrations directory and the aerich settings file, running any command f.e.
"`aerich migrate` or `aerich inspectdb`" throws me the error that I put in the title:
***Error while importing configuration module: No module named 'app'***.

**Here is my setup**:

[image: config package init file that contains required TORTOISE-ORM settings for aerich]
<sup>*config package init file that contains required TORTOISE-ORM settings for aerich*</sup>

[image: the generated aerich settings file using aerich init -t app.config.TORTOISE_ORM command]
<sup>*the generated aerich settings file using `aerich init -t app.config.TORTOISE_ORM` command*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed in 0.5.7 version of aerich.